# Get the number of elements that are displayed using WebdriverIO v5

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I tried to get the number of elements that have a certain tag Name, using webdriverIO v5 and Javascript.
`console.log()` is printing all of them, but the variable in which the number of the elements is stored has always the value 0. What am I missing?

```
confirmSearchingResultPageHasOnlyTenElements() {
        this.searchBox.waitForEnabled(8000, false);
        this.searchBox.setValue('xyz');
        this.searchButton.waitForClickable({ timeout: 8000 });
        this.searchButton.click();
        var results = browser.findElements("tag name", 'article').values.length;
        console.log(results)
        expect(results).to.be.equal(10);
        results[3].click();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

please upgrade to the latest version of WebdriverIO (v6) if you haven't yet.

You can do something like this:

```
const elements = $$('article')
// expect lib waits for assertion to pass
// in this case it waits for elements to have length 3
expect(elements).toBeElementsArrayOfSize(3) // there are exactly 3 `article` elements
// or expect(elements).toBeElementsArrayOfSize({ get: 3 }) // 3 or more `article` elements

expect(elements).toBeVisible() // make sure all the article elements are visible
```

Comment: I managed to do that in this way:

 get results() { return $$("[class='productItem__name']"); }


  confirmSearchingResultPageHasOnlyTenElements() {
        this.results.values.length;
        expect(this.results.length).to.be.lessThan(11);
    }

Comment: I believe this is v4? It's not supported and maintained couple of years already. Consider upgrading to v6!

Comment: It is v5 but I definetely have to upgrade it to v6

Answer (score 0):

You are using `findElements` this returns a list of webElements that have "tag name": 'article'.

You can check each element `element.isDisplayed();` and count them.